# Multi Selection Dropdown using CardService

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, multi-select, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am working on Drive Add-on,  and got stuck at implementing Multi Selection Dropdown using Card Services in Google App Script.

[image]

Tried to implement the text box input with Suggestion parameters but once a keyword is selected, suggestion does not appear again for more keyword to enter.

Open to all suggestions to implement multiple selection.

I have created a text input with the help of Card services in GAS

[image]

if clicked on text input here are the suggestions I get
[image]

after I select one of the suggestion I am unable to generate  another fresh list of suggestions.

Comment: Please add more information to (and code) to your question. See [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Please post the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *the code*

Comment: Hello @abhishekpramanik did you got any solution for this?
how you make this multi select dropdown? Can you please post here?